# TLSharp exception во время чтения сообщений

Tags: c#, telegram

Я читаю сообщения из чата используя следующий код:

```
    public async Task GatherChatHistory(string channelName, string ch_id, string mid, int offset = 0, int minId = 0, int maxId = -1, int limit = 100)
    {
        Log.Info(Tag, "In GatherChatHistory Start");
        TelegramClient client = CreateClient();
        await InitializeAndAuthenticateClient(client);

        int maximal = Convert.ToInt32(mid);

        Log.Info(Tag, "In GatherChatHistory Before GetUserDialogAsync");

        try
        {
            var dialogs = (TLDialogs)await client.GetUserDialogsAsync();
            var chat = dialogs.chats.lists
                .OfType<TLChat>()
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c.title == channelName);

            Log.Info(Tag, "In GatherChatHistory After GetUserDialogAsync " + (chat != null));

            if (chat != null)
            {
                Log.Info(Tag, "Chat != null, " + channelName);
                try
                {
                    var tlAbsMessages =
                        await client.GetHistoryAsync(
                            new TLInputPeerChat { chat_id = chat.id }, offset,
                            minId, maxId, limit);
                    Log.Info(Tag, "After GetHistoryAsync");

                    var tlChannelMessages = (TLMessages)tlAbsMessages;
                    Log.Info(Tag, "GatherChatHistory Messages count = " + (tlChannelMessages.messages.lists.Count - 1));

                    for (var index = 0; index < tlChannelMessages.messages.lists.Count - 1; index++)
                    {
                        var tlAbsMessage = tlChannelMessages.messages.lists[index];
                        Log.Info(Tag, "Message Type = " + tlAbsMessage.GetType());
                        if (tlAbsMessage.GetType().ToString().Equals("TeleSharp.TL.TLMessageService"))
                            continue;
                        var message = (TLMessage)tlAbsMessage;

                        if (message.id == maximal)
                        {
                            Log.Info(Tag, "GatherChatHistory Chat_id = " + channelName + " maximal was reached");
                            break;
                        }
                        if (message.id <= maximal)
                        {
                            Log.Info(Tag, "GatherChatHistory Chat_id = " + channelName + " message.id = " + message.id + " maxid = " + maximal);
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (message.media == null)
                        {
                            Log.Info(Tag, "Message ID = " + message.id);
                            Log.Info(Tag, "Chat ID = " + chat.id);
                            Log.Info(Tag, "Content = " + message.message);
                            await AddNewMessageToDatabase(channelName, ch_id, message.message, null, message.from_id.GetValueOrDefault(), message.id);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            switch (message.media.GetType().ToString())
                            {
                                case "TeleSharp.TL.TLMessageMediaPhoto":
                                    var tLMessageMediaPhoto = (TLMessageMediaPhoto)message.media;
                                    var photo = (TLPhoto)tLMessageMediaPhoto.photo;
                                    var photoSize = photo.sizes.lists.OfType<TLPhotoSize>().Last();
                                    TLFileLocation tf = (TLFileLocation)photoSize.location;
                                    var resFile = await client.GetFile(new TLInputFileLocation
                                    {

                                        local_id = tf.local_id,
                                        secret = tf.secret,
                                        volume_id = tf.volume_id
                                    },               0, -1);

                                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(resFile.bytes))
                                    {
                                        byte[] byteArr = ms.ToArray();
                                        string base64image = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArr);
                                        Log.Info(Tag, "Caption = " + tLMessageMediaPhoto.caption);
                                        Log.Info(Tag, "Base64 Image = " + base64image);
                                        await AddNewMessageToDatabase(channelName, ch_id, tLMessageMediaPhoto.caption, base64image, message.from_id.GetValueOrDefault(), message.id);
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "TeleSharp.TL.TLMessageMediaDocument":
                                    var tLMessageMediaDocument = (TLMessageMediaDocument)message.media;
                                    break;
                                case "TeleSharp.TL.TLMessageMediaWebPage":
                                    var tLMessageMediaWebPage = (TLMessageMediaWebPage)message.media;
                                    string url = string.Empty;
                                    if (tLMessageMediaWebPage.webpage.GetType().ToString() != "TeleSharp.TL.TLWebPageEmpty")
                                    {
                                        var webPage = (TLWebPage)tLMessageMediaWebPage.webpage;
                                        url = webPage.url;
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Logger.Error("Telegram Chat History exception: " + e.Message);
                    Log.Error(Tag, "Telegram Chat History exception: " + e.Message);
                    Log.Error(Tag, "Telegram Chat History StackTrace = " + e.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
                Log.Info(Tag, "Chat == null");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(Tag, "ReadUserAsync Error : " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

У меня нет никаких проблем с чтением текстовых сообщений, но если в промежуток между вызовами этой функции в чат попало более одной фотографии, то нормально считывается только одна, при считывании второй при вызове GetFile возникает exception:

```
[MessagingService:TelegramBridge] Telegram Chat History exception: msg_seqno 
too low (the server has already received a message with a lower msg_id but 
with either a higher or an equal and odd seqno)
[MessagingService:TelegramBridge] Telegram Chat History StackTrace = 
System.InvalidOperationException: msg_seqno too low (the server has already 
received a message with a lower msg_id but with either a higher or an equal 
and odd seqno)
[MessagingService:TelegramBridge]   at 
TLSharp.Core.Network.MtProtoSender.HandleBadMsgNotification (System.UInt64 
messageId, System.Int32 sequence, System.IO.BinaryReader messageReader) 
[0x0009f] in <24dee86ac15149c89ccf3cac229b439d>:0 
[MessagingService:TelegramBridge]   at 
TLSharp.Core.Network.MtProtoSender.processMessage (System.UInt64 messageId, 
System.Int32 sequence, System.IO.BinaryReader messageReader, 
TeleSharp.TL.TLMethod request) [0x00182] in 
<24dee86ac15149c89ccf3cac229b439d>:0 
[MessagingService:TelegramBridge]   at TLSharp.Core.Network.MtProtoSender+
<Receive>d__9.MoveNext () [0x000bb] in <24dee86ac15149c89ccf3cac229b439d>:0
```

При этом часть кода, связанная с TLSharp перестает работать совсем до перезагрузки программы. Может, кто-то сталкивался с таким?